# How can pressure act in both the up and down direction?

Tags: forces, pressure, free-body-diagram, fluid-statics

[image]

It says in my textbook that pressure is a vector. So how does it act both in the up and down direction in the same body of water as seen in this image?

Comment: Well, suppose the can had a vacuum in it. Would it feel pressure upwards on the bottom and downwards on the top? So then we use a can with beans in it. It would feel the same pressure.

Comment: I don't think pressure can be something super simple.  Force is a vector, while area is a pseudovector.  Within the context of special relativity, force generalizes to a 4-vector, while area (since it's formed from a cross product of two vectors) generalizes to a 4x4 matrix (second rank tensor).  When I asked my professors about relativist versions of thermodynamic quantities, they gave me leads to where to find some answers (there's whole books on relativistic temperature), but they didn't seem super-interested all the time.

Comment: @DevinJC, pressure doesn't act in the up and down direction at the same time ... the force due to pressure always acts perpendicular to the surface that it is contacting.  In your case, the object is oriented in a way that causes force to act up on the bottom surface and down on the top surface.

Answer (score 3):

The pressure is not a vector. It is the force per unit area, and the force acts perpendicularly to the area. The pressure in fluid is due the motion of the molecules. The force arises because of momentum exchanges. Since the molecules are in motion randomly in every direction there is an exchange of momentum with different planes. The momentum transfer occurs in a direction perpendicular to the plane. It is therefore acting in every direction at every point in a fluid.

When gravity is considered, the weight of the fluid provides the force. When acts on the top and bottom surfaces it provides a pressure. So between two depths there is a difference in the weight of the fluid. Imagine replacing the can of beans with a circular cylinder of the same size and let it be a volume of fluid of mass $m$ and cross-sectional area, i.e. the area of the flat circular flace of the can) be $A$ and height $h$ we find that in equilibrium the forces sum to zero to give

$$P_b A - P_t A = mg\,,$$
where $P_{b}$ is the pressure at the bottom of the mass of fluid (the bottom of the can in this case) and $P_{t}$ is the pressure at the top of the mass of fluid (the top of the can in your question.)

For a fluid of constant density $\rho$ the mass is given by $m=\rho V$. Writing $V=Ah$ we obtain

$$P_bA-P_tA = \rho Ahg\,.$$

Dividing across by the cross-sectional area, which is the area of the circular face of the can of beans in your question, we get

$$P_b - P_t = \rho gh\,.$$

See Cutnell & Johnson's "Essentials of Physics."

Edit: Upon reading further, I discovered that pressure in a fluid is also due to the interatomic/intermolecular forces. There are molecules all around a single individual molecule and they are in motion and exerting forces on each other. This explains why the pressure acts in every direction in a liquid. Thus pressure is not a vector. The microscopic explanation of pressure in a liquid is discussed in the answer to the Physics StackExchange question [Microscopic interpretation of pressure in liquids](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/275018/microscopic-interpretation-of-pressure-in-liquids)

Comment: I just dont understand how it causes an upwards force, when the pressure is caused by the weight of the water above, which acts downwards :/.

Comment: @DevinJC Because the pressure exerted by the water on the top of the can is less than the pressure exerted by the water on the bottom of the can. The force is related to the _change_ in pressure across the can (i.e. the pressure gradient), which _is_ a vector quantity. But the pressure itself is still a scalar.

Comment: @probably_someone I get why it happens I just dont get why the pressure acts upwards when the all the force arises from the weight of the water, which acts downwards. idk I guess I'm just thinking about it all wrong. Many thanks for your replies though.

Comment: @DevinJC As a trivial example of this effect, grab a packet of Ketchup.  Put it on the ground, and stomp on it *hard*.  The ketchup will exert a pressure rather strongly in all directions, the packaging will fail in one direction, and that pressure will cause the ketchup to shoot everywhere.  The pressure drives the ketchup outwards, even though you only applied downarward force.

Comment: With a bit of cleverness, you can also set up an experiment with a pinprick hole in the top surface of the packet, and you can press down on the rest of the packet with your hand.  Ketchup will squirt *up*, even though your hand is applying force downward.  (What may help is to note that the table underneath the packet is also applying an upwards force, as is the sea floor in your textbook image)

Comment: @DevinJC What you're forgetting is the normal force exerted by the water that the bottom of the can is resting on. If the bottom of the can was resting on the ground, then it would be perfectly obvious that there should be a normal force; the ground exerts an upward reaction force, even though the weight of the ground still points downwards. The same is true here: the upward force on the bottom of the can is a kind of normal force caused by the interaction of the water directly below the can with the water around it (and eventually, the walls of the container the water is in).

Comment: I totally get your point of confusion, as I once had the same conundrum. One way to address it think about what is holding the water up when you're in the depths? It's water molecules moving up and bouncing off H2Os above them. Well, they move randomly in all directions, so there is pressure is in all directions. Check out "the equation of state", which relates density to temperature and pressure.

Answer (score 3):

Pressure isn't really a vector, but it's related to a lot of vector quantities. Pressure* is actually a scalar (i.e. it's "just a number;" it has a magnitude, but not a direction, at any point in space); specifically, it's a scalar that is derived from a more complicated object called the *stress tensor* which contains information about the forces at every point in space in a material. Since forces are vectors, and forces are the inputs for the stress tensor which eventually gives rise to the pressure, one might be able to say that *pressure is derived from vector quantities*, which is basically what your diagram shows.

Another way in which pressure is related to vector quantities is when calculating the buoyant force. Doing such a calculation requires that you take the *gradient* of the pressure; the gradient is an operation that converts a scalar function into a vector function. Specifically, it describes how much, and in what direction, the pressure changes as you move through a material. So it's also true that *the pressure gradient is a vector*, which is basically what @zeta-band is getting at in the comments.

*Technically, what I'm referring to here is *static pressure*, as opposed to *dynamic pressure*, because that's what your diagram appears to refer to. If your textbook actually meant dynamic pressure (i.e. the kinetic energy of moving fluid), then that's still a scalar, but there's a closely related quantity, the *momentum density*, which is a vector.

Comment: I like the air quotes in a scalar is "just a number", since it's not just a number, esp. in regards to this question. As the rotationally invariant part of the stress tensor (the trace), it's a number that is also a geometric object--the simplest geometric object, but a geometric object nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Pressure is an ambiguous word.   I can apply pressure to a thumbtack,
and that's a force, and is a vector.   But, we also speak of air pressure, or hydraulic pressure, referring to a scalar quantity called
hydrostatic pressure.   The difference is, hydrostatic pressure is
quantified as force per unit area and represents the fact that
any small bit of a fluid can push its way out of a container,
in any direction.

Squeeze a poly bottle of mustard, and the sideways force of
your hand pressurizes the interior, and it squirts... up, down,
or wherever the nozzle points.  The force of your hands on
the sides of the bottle is vector force (and if you push one-sided,
the bottle accelerates), but the pressure of the contained mustard
is hydraulic pressure, which can propel the mustard through
any opening, in any direction.

The behavior of incompressible fluids (constant volume but no
particular shape) makes useful working devices, with the
hydraulic pressure as an important variable, but that variable
wasn't given a one-word name that distinguishes it from my
thumb pressing a thumbtack.   And the behavior of compressible
fluids (like the air in a tire) is also useful,
in a different, spring-like way.  It's called pressure, too, or
hydrostatic pressure (but usually not hydraulic pressure).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this simple example shows you that pressure is not a vector.

In the diagram below the dashed line $AB$ is horizontal and the can is immersed in a fluid.
The pressure at each point along line $AB$ is the same.

[image]

Note what happens when the top of the can of beans is placed along line $AB$ and then the bottom of the can is placed along line $AB$.

In both cases the ends of the can experience the same pressure, however, the force which is exerted on the end of the can is reversed.

It is the force $\vec F$ exerted by the fluid which is the vector quantity.

Possibly the confusion arises because pressure is defined as force divided by area $P=\frac FA$ and because the right hand side of the defining equation is a vector $\vec F$ so must be the left hand which is the pressure.

However this is not correct because the force direction is actually related to the orientation of the area; the force is at right angles to the area.

How can this be written as a vector equation which defines pressure?

The **area** is made a vector quantity using the relationship $\Delta \vec A = \Delta A \,\hat n$ where $\Delta A$ is the area and $\hat n$ is a unit vector which is at right angles to the area.
The use of $\Delta$s is to show that even if you have a large surface which is curved that curved surface can be thought of as being made up of many small surfaces which are planar.

Now one can write $\Delta \vec F = - P \, \Delta A \,\hat n$ as the defining vector equation for pressure with the pressure as a scalar.

[image]

The minus sign is there because the direction of the normal to the area is opposite to the direction of the force exerted by the fluid.

Converting this to a scalar equation is simple.

$\Delta \vec F = - P \, \Delta A \,\hat n \Rightarrow \Delta F \,(-\hat n) = - P \, \Delta A \,\hat n \Rightarrow \Delta F = P\,\Delta A$